# Renaming the iCloud folder in the Terminal, but not renaming the actual file itself

Tags: terminal, icloud, bash

Is there a way for me to give my iCloud directory a "nickname" in the Terminal, that way I don't have to see "~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs" in front of each line, but rather, can just see "iCloud" and know I'm in said directory?

Comment: can't you do a link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about creating a symbolic link to that directory on your Desktop or in another easily accessible directory?

```
ln -s ~/"Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs" ~/Desktop/iCloud
```

Note that you need to have the `~/` outside of the double quotes in order for the link to correctly resolve to your home directory, otherwise it will try to link to the literal directory `~` which of course won't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Generic unix-y answer is to create a soft link:

```
cd ~
ln -s "Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs" myShortName
```

Now you can:

```
cd ~/myShortName/
```

Notes:

- The new name will also appear in the finder.
- if you `cd -P ~/myShortName` or use `pwd -P` in that directory, you will see the full `...~CloudDocs` path

  - For more about this see the "SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS" section of `man bash`